# How do I use the 'Display Wrapper Attributes' feature?

Tags: webforms

EDIT:  Let's forget I ever mentioned the word 'email'.  Can someone please explain to me how this part of the Webform (for Drupal 8) v5.x is supposed to work?

---

The image below is from the 'Advanced' tab of a custom composite element in a Drupal Webform.  The element is creating an unordered list `<ul>` in HTML-speak.  The list items `<li>` are, in turn, a list of information.  I would like to create some space between the bottom of one `<li>` item and the top of the next one.

In the 'Submission Display' section of the 'Advanced' tab of the element I'm building for the webform, is a way to add 'Display CSS classes' and/or 'Display CSS style'.  As you can see, I know how to create the 'custom' CSS class here; but, then what do I do to tell Drupal or Webform to do stuff WITH the custom class?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Webform doesn't have any special feature for adding CSS.

The normal way to add CSS in Drupal is to create a subtheme of your site's theme and then add a custom stylesheet there.  This is a bit complicated to set up but is the recommended approach for long-term maintainability.

However, if you just want to define one or two css classes to clean up your webform, setting up a subtheme may seem like overkill.  In that case, you can use the [Asset Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector) module to add custom CSS (or JS) as you like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Respectfully, your answer is a bit broader than I am looking for.  I'm sure there are other ways to format this submission email, using different tactics -- customizing the email handler, adding a module, etc. -- but then what is the purpose of having Display Wrapper Attributes in the Webform module?

Comment: AFAIK, display wrapper attributes are for showing the display within Drupal, not in an email.  Email formatting is handled in modules like Swift Mailer and is not part of webform.